# How to fix retargeting warning

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a .Net solution that produces the following warning when compiled using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 on a Win7 x64 build agent using .Net 4.5.2. The projects in the solution all target the .Net 4.5.2 framework:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (991):
>   The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"
>   were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for
>   this framework version or retarget your application to a version of
>   the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.

Can someone explain what I need to do to resolve this? Somewhere else refers to 'repairing the Windows SDK' but if indeed that is the solution I am not sure what that entails.

Should I even be worried about this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637